# Shipping Carrier Abstract integer

Tags: shipping

Working with Shipping Carrier rates, I came to know about function **convertWeightToLbs()** located at

```
Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php
```

The function is

```
     *  Return weight in pounds
     *  @param integer Weight in someone measure
     *  @return float Weight in pounds
     */
    public function convertWeightToLbs($weight)
    {
        return $weight;
    }
```

The parameter passed in the above function is **integer Weight in someone measure** and return value is **float Weight in pounds**.

Could anyone explain how and where Magento uses this function along with its params and return values i.e. integer in and float out.

Answer (score 1):

This function does nothing, looks like a placeholder.